# Could a normal desktop user create his/her own bootable disk?

Tags: live-usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)

I ask this, because it would make my life a lot easier if I could have a bootable CD or USB stick with all my favorite applications, games, and codecs preinstalled.

Comment: What do you mean by "normal desktop user"? Are some users not normal?

Comment: By normal I meant people who are not experts in using the command line, and don't know how to manually edit files

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a persistent live session on a pen drive. You may want to grab the DVD image if your pen drive is big enough (the DVD image is ~1.5 GB and includes the GIMP). Then once you boot from USB, in the software center feel free to install all the apps you like, including your favorite games and codecs. You should be able to install them in the same way you installed them in Ubuntu running off your internal hard drive.

Customizing a live CD is not as easy, and I'd say less n00b friendly, but fortunately there's plenty of great documentation that can help n00bs do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, titaniumtux. I will give it a try, and let you guys know the result.